# How to copy files between two open SSH shells?

Tags: linux, ssh, file-transfer

If I am logged in via SSH on 2 servers and want to copy some files from one to the other (e.g. configuration from an old to a new server), what's the easiest way to do that?

Answer (score 3):

On server1:

```
scp <files> server2:/dest/dir/
```

Or, if you have rsync installed:

```
rsync -azvu basedir/ server2:destdir/
```

If not, pipe through tar then:

```
tar cf -  -C srcdir | ssh server2 tar xf - -C dstdir
```

The last two copy entire directory trees. The first one or more files in a directory.

In other words, just use shell tools from the first one to copy directly to the second one.

Comment: That would require a login though (which gets harder if it involves keys) and does not allow something like `sudo` (well, maybe the pipe-tar-through SSH one does?). But it is the most practical way to transfer larger data.

Comment: It does allow it. Just put a "sudo" in there. You can set up public key authentication to make it passwordless.

Answer (score 2):

If the total size isn't too big, one can use this little trick.

1. One the source server, do `tar -cz <filestocopy> | base64`
2. Copy the output to clipboard
3. On the destination server, do `base64 -d | tar -xzv`
4. Paste, enter, Ctrl-D

---

How does this work?

1. Creates a compressed tar of the files and base64 encodes it so it can be copy-pasted as plain text.
2. Sets up a command chain that does the reverse; decodes base64 input and extracts the tar.
3. Paste the data to feed it into that chain, then enter and Ctrl-D to send the end-of-file.

Answer (score 2):

With two open ssh sessions the fastest way to copy would be:

1. Use netcat (nc)

   ```
   Sender/Source machine:
   tar -czf - /source/dir | nc -l 2342

   Receiver/Destination machine:
   nc -w 10 sourcemachine 2342 | tar -C /target/dir -xz -
   ```
2. Use scp with less secure encryption. The default is blowfish usually but arcfour is a much faster alternative.

   ```
   scp -c arcfour mogga@flinflon:/home/users/mogga /dev/null
   ```

I usually use the second option (simply because I can remember it more often).

Comment: Interesting. I'm currently working on EC2 servers where I would have to open up an extra port for that, but I could use that port for other tools as well.

Comment: Just tested it and it works well. Small error: the `-p` option (source option) should not be there in the destination command.

Comment: oops...you're right. 
`-p source_port  
    Specifies the source port nc should use, subject to privilege
    restrictions and availability.  It is an error to use this option in
    conjunction with the -l option.`